# For attribute on label does not interact with associated input on click when id and for property are bound

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a fairly simple component that should be outputting a checkbox and label.  There are four inputs on the component: `id`, `name`, `label`, and `value`.

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="checkbox col-xs-12" *ngIf="id && name && label && value">
    <input type="checkbox" [id]="id" [name]="name" [value]="value">
    <label [for]="id" id="{{id}}-label" aria-label="not here">{{label}}</label>
</div>
```

When the `id` attribute on the input and the `for` attribute on the label are bound to data via `[]`, clicking on the label does nothing.

If I hardcode the `id` and `for` attributes, they work just fine.

Using `[attr.id]` and `[attr.for]` yield the same non-working results.

What is going on here?

The resulting html is exactly what you would expected:

```
<div _ngcontent-wam-3="" class="checkbox col-xs-12">
    <input _ngcontent-wam-3="" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-id="bob" id="bob" ng-reflect-name="bobby" name="bobby" ng-reflect-value="true" value="true">
    <label _ngcontent-wam-3="" aria-label="not here" ng-reflect-html-for="bob" for="bob" ng-reflect-id="bob-label" id="bob-label">Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you really wrapped so many attribute-names in square-brackets, or is that just for here? For some reason? If it's in your real code then that could be why it's not working (though perhaps angular and typescript do something useful with that?); if it's just for us here on SO then please show the real HTML.

Comment: ... that is the real html.  Those properties are bound to associated input values in the component.  It is called like: `<my-checkbox name="bob" value="true" id="bob1" label="For Bob"></my-checkbox>`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the resulting HTML, as you see in 'view source' or in the DOM; that format seems to be unnecessarily confusing (though that may be my inexperience with that particular component).

Comment: added resulting markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this bug was because the `id` attribute on the custom element takes precedent over the resulting `id` attribute on the actual checkbox or radio button.  Changing the `id` input to `idStr` lets everything work as expected.

example:

```
<my-checkbox name="bob" value="true" idStr="bob1" label="For Bob"></my-checkbox>
```